# Javascript loop and dupe key data

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to ajax and have the below query that is working well however get the following warnings

"Duplicate key "data" "
and
"Don't make functions with loops"

Should i worry about this and if so how should i fix them.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) 
    {
        var str = localStorage.key(i);
        var dataValue = localStorage.getItem(str);

        if(str.substring(0,5) === "token")
        {   
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + "task/save_response",
                data: "username="+localStorage.getItem('user')+"&password="+localStorage.getItem('password'),
                data: dataValue,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
            }).done(function(msg) {
                localStorage.removeItem(str);
            });
        }
        else if(str.substring(0,8) === "fileinfo")
        {
            $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + "task/save_file_info",
                    data: "username="+localStorage.getItem('user')+"&password="+localStorage.getItem('password'),
                    data: dataValue,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
            }).done(function(msg) {
                localStorage.removeItem(str);
            });
        }
        else if(str.substring(0,5) === "photo")
        {
            uploadPhoto(dataValue);
            localStorage.removeItem(str);
        }
    } //end for
```

Comment: You get the warnings from what? And another question: do you think having the `data` property in the object twice makes any sense?

Comment: Duplicate key "data" comes from the fact that you send two "data" params in your post. Here you are launching a ajax request for each localStorage item... You might want to do only one request to fetch all your data

Comment: I get the warning In my code editor. But the code works fine. as for data i want to send that data i guess i can just remove the second data. (as to above comment)

Comment: data: "username="+localStorage.getItem('user')+"&password="+localStorage.getItem('password')+localStorage.getItem(str), changed line to like this but am i correct in saying that if i add data twice it will read both lines but this is just a better way of doing it

Comment: Is the for loop a problem?